# concatenation in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

Here is the code in my batch file

```
set startdate="9/1/2011"
set enddate="10/31/2011"

sqlcmd -Q "exec mysp '%startdate%', '%enddate%'"
```

I want to execute the command in SQL Server:

```
exec mysp '9/1/2011', '10/31/2011'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you haven't exactly told us what's going *wrong* but I'm guessing the double quotes arond the dates are being included in the command, as per:

```
C:\Users\Pax> set startdate="9/1/2011"

C:\Users\Pax> echo %startdate%
"9/1/2011"

C:\Users\Pax> set startdate=9/1/2011

C:\Users\Pax> echo %startdate%
9/1/2011
```

Try removing them.

Comment: It looks like the code was actually working with or without quotes. It must have been me trying a bunch of tests in between that was breaking it.